# Line plot using means of data and grouping

Tags: r, statistics, mean, linegraph

`df` is this:

```
gender party mean(salary)

1 female democrat 31833.33    
2 female republican 27000.00    
3 male democrat 30250.00    
4 male republican 36166.67
```

Make a line graph of the means for male democrats, female democrats, male republicans, and female republicans, with all means shown in a single graph, and error bars showing 95% confidence intervals. Plot the political affiliation on the x-axis and the salary on the y-axis. Identify the lines for male and female means by a change in line boldness, symbol shape, color, or dash style.

This is my attempt:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=party, y='mean(salary)', group=gender)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=gender))+
  geom_point(aes(color=gender)+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", position = position_dodge(width = 0.90),width=0.2))
```

And it turns out like one flat line from democrat to republican.

Here is my raw data as per request:

```
salary party gender
1 34000 republican male
2 31000 republican female
3 28000 democrat male
4 29000 democrat female
5 30000 republican male
6 23000 republican female
7 27500 democrat male
8 32000 democrat female
9 32000 republican male
10 28000 republican female
11 30000 democrat male
12 34000 democrat female
13 39000 republican male
14 27000 republican female
15 34000 democrat male
16 30000 democrat female
17 40000 republican male
18 26000 republican female
19 30000 democrat male
20 35000 democrat female
21 42000 republican male
22 27000 republican female
23 32000 democrat male
24 31000 democrat female
```

Comment: You have `x = party` in your aesthetic, resulting in `party` representing your x-axis. But it is unclear exactly what you want. Could you describe further what your plot should look like (line vs. bar plot, what should the axis be, etc.)? Also, your `df` looks like it has summarized mean values already, did you want to plot those same exact values? From those means, were standard errors already computed and available elsewhere? Another approach is for you to provide example raw data if you have it, and you could receive help on both summarizing and plotting further.

Comment: Okay, I have added some more details and I have added the raw data

Answer (score 0):

While you could create a line graph, maybe you might be interested in a bar plot instead? This might be more appealing with nominal categories like political party.

Here is one approach, using `dplyr` and `ggplot2`. First determine the mean and standard deviation for each `party` and `gender` combination. Then, you can use `geom_bar` and `geom_errorbar` to plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(party, gender) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(salary),
            sd=sd(salary)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=party, y=mean, fill=gender)) +
    geom_bar(position=position_dodge(width=.75), stat = "identity", width=.7) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), position=position_dodge(width=.75), width=.3)
```

**Plot**

[image: bar plot]

Answer (score 0):

Not to discourage you from learning to do it yourself, but I have a small package that offers a function that will do what you want plus offers lots of formatting options. `CGPfunctions::Plot2WayANOVA`

```r
library(CGPfunctions)
CGPfunctions::Plot2WayANOVA(salary ~ party * gender, salary_df)
#> 
#> Converting party to a factor --- check your results
#> 
#> Converting gender to a factor --- check your results
#> 
#> Blah blah lots of important info to the console ...
#> Interaction graph plotted...
```

[image]

Manually it goes something like this...

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# summarise what we need
salary_summarised <- salary_df %>%
   group_by(party, gender) %>%
   summarise(
      AVG.salary = mean(salary, na.rm=TRUE),
      SD.salary = sd(salary, na.rm=TRUE),
      N.salary = length(salary),
      SE.salary = sd(salary, na.rm=TRUE) / sqrt(length(salary)),
      CI95Muliplier = qt(.95/2 + .5, length(salary) - 1)
   )


# and plot it
ggplot(salary_summarised, 
       aes(x=party, 
           y=AVG.salary, 
           colour=gender, 
           group=gender)) +
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=AVG.salary - SE.salary*CI95Muliplier, 
                     ymax=AVG.salary + SE.salary*CI95Muliplier), 
                 width=.2, 
                 color = "purple") +
   geom_line() +
   geom_point(aes(y=AVG.salary)) +
   xlab("Party") +
   ylab("Salary") +
   ggtitle("Salary with 95% CI") +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

Using your data sample

```r
library(readr)
salary_df <- readr::read_table2("salary party gender
34000 republican male
31000 republican female
28000 democrat male
29000 democrat female
30000 republican male
23000 republican female
27500 democrat male
32000 democrat female
32000 republican male
28000 republican female
30000 democrat male
34000 democrat female
39000 republican male
27000 republican female
34000 democrat male
30000 democrat female
40000 republican male
26000 republican female
30000 democrat male
35000 democrat female
42000 republican male
27000 republican female
32000 democrat male
31000 democrat female")
```